# Error Linkedin sign up button after minifying code

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

This is the script I put on the head tag for my Linkedin sign up button

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: 11zs8h6jybgd66
  onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
  authorize: true
</script>
```

It worked correctly ultil I minify my code, after that, it goes like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"> api_key: 11zs8h6jybgd66 onLoad: onLinkedInLoad authorize: true </script>
```

And the error I have in my Chrome console is: **Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.**

I've tried surrounding my variables api_key with inverted commas ("") or putting a comma (,) at the end of the rows but nothing is working with the minified code.

Somebody had the same problem? Any ideas on how can this Linkedin's script works even if it's minified?

Answer (score 2):

Well, read the bottom section of this documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#

> Important!
>
> The line breaks between the arguments within the 
>   tags are important since there is no other form of field separator. 
>   If you are using a templating language or code minifier that strips
>   whitespace from your rendered HTML, be aware that you will need to
>   make an exception to preserve the line-breaks within this 
>   tag, otherwise they will not be parsed properly.